# How do I export multiple interfaces in a nested way in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm, es6-modules

I have a pretty large npm module written in TypeScript, which exposes a number of types, including several interfaces. Now these interfaces do not all make sense at the root level, which is why I would like to expose them in a way that they can be imported in a somewhat nested way.

Basically, I'm looking for a way to expose interface so that the user of the module can do:

```
import { Foo } from 'my-module';
import { Bar } from 'my-module/sub-part';
```

Is this possible in TypeScript, and if so, how? What does *not* work is this code in the root `index.ts` file:

```
export {
  Foo,
  { Bar }
};
```

Please note that the `.ts` files are not located at the root directory of the module, and so the `.js` and `.d.ts` files aren't either.

How can I solve this?

PS: It's not about default vs named export here, since I want to have a solution for exporting interfaces in *multiple* nested levels.

Comment: The usual approach, AFAICT, is to put a `package.json` file in the `sub-part` directory in your package's root and use the `main` and `types` entries in that file (they're gonna be the only ones you need to specify) to refer to the `.d.ts` and `.js` files - which can be anywhere you like.

Comment: Maybe you could use: `declare module "my-module/sub-part" { export interface Bar { … } }`?

Comment: Edited my answer. Let me know, if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the easiest case, you just have separate `index.d.ts` files inside the `my-module` and `my-module/sub-part` folder of the published npm package, so we can import `my-module` and `my-module/sub-part` separately. Example project directory:

```
my-module
|   dist
│   index.ts
│   package.json // types prop e.g. could point to dist/index.d.ts
│
└───sub-part
        index.ts // compiled to dist/sub-part/index.d.ts
```

TS makes use of its [module resolution process](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html) to resolve `my-module` or `my-module/sub-part` imports (given no global type declaration like `@types` exists). For example, `my-module` in `import { Foo } from 'my-module'` is resolved like [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#how-typescript-resolves-modules):

```
// first, try to find file directly
node_modules/my-module.ts
node_modules/my-module.tsx
node_modules/my-module.d.ts

// look in package.json for types property pointing to a file
node_modules/my-module/package.json // <-- lands here, if "types" prop exists

// look in @types
node_modules/@types/my-module.d.ts

// treat my-module as folder and look for an index file
node_modules/my-module/index.ts
node_modules/my-module/index.tsx
node_modules/my-module/index.d.ts // <-- lands here otherwise
```

For the sake of completness here, `my-module` and `my-module/sub-part` could also be defined as separate [global module declarations](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#ambient-modules) in one containing file, like:

```
declare module "my-module" {
  const Foo: string
}

declare module "my-module/sub-part" {
  const Bar: number
}
```

Finally, the client code looks like you already pictured:

```
import { Foo } from "my-module";
import { Bar } from "my-module/sub-part";

console.log(Foo)
```

Hope, it helps.